# Блокировать отправку писем по получателю (полю "To") на уровне сервера MTA

Tags: postfix, exim

Как можно запретить отправку писем на современных MTA (Exim и Postfix) по получателю (поле `To`)?

Кейс: необходимо отписать email из рассылок. Рассылок много, формируются в разных не связанных системах, вычистить везде невозможно. Есть идея запретить отправку на такие email по некоторому списку на почтовом relay.

Comment: `google:exim+discard+recipient` — первые пара ссылок дадут достаточно примеров.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, спасибо, гугл мучал, но видать не так :)